# My code modifies the group in both cases though I only need it to be modified when it is 1

Tags: php

```
<?php 
include('conn.php');
if(isset($_GET['Valider'])) {
  $req="select acc from demch ";
  $rs=mysql_query($req) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
//while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)){ 
$acc=$row['acc'];
    if($acc=1){
$req1= "UPDATE etudiant, demch
   SET etudiant.groupe=demch.grpdes WHERE etudiant.dem_id=demch.dem_id ";
   $rs1=mysql_query($req1) or die (mysql_error());
   }
   elseif($acc=0){
    $req2="UPDATE etudiant SET message='votre demande est refuser' WHERE etudiant.dem_id=demch.dem_id ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($req2) or die (mysql_error());
   }
  }}//}
      ?>
```

it changes the group in both cases though I need it to be changed  only if it 1

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Uh oh `if($acc=1)` will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($acc=1){
```

Should be

```
if($acc==1){
```

Or also

```
if($acc===1){
```

Cause right now you're not checking anything in your condition, you are just setting `$acc` value to 1.

Comment: `if($acc==1)` *Or even better*. **Well it is always depended on the situation**

Comment: thank you gregoire ducharme ..   but still an error